# How to round off numbers in Python3.7.2

Tags: python-3.x, decimal

I would like some assistance into rounding off a answer in Python

```
fuel = 9.95
print("Initial Price is:",fuel)

tax = 0.095
fuelTax = (fuel * tax)
print(fuelTax)
```

I would like it that upon printing, the answer is rounded to x decimal places. As of right now, it prints out a float with a lot of decimal places. I just started learning how to code, and would appreciate any tips/pointers you guys have. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the builtin `round(number, digits)` function to obtain the expected result
[Bultin functions docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)

Comment: Could you show me where to implement the function? I tried doing so but returned the error "int" object is not callable